# Why is base colour wheel only giving me black as an option

Tags: animation, materials, color

I don't know when this happened but my base colour wheel doesn't want to cooperate to give me the colours that i want. The problem:

[image]

How do i get the colour wheel to show all the colours again and what did i do to make this happen? Thanks!

ps: Not sure if this is related but the animation i have for the + signs are changing alpha value from 0 to 1, using alpha blend as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have set the luminosity to a low level. Bring it up.

[image]

The circle is to set hue and saturation. The strip to the right is to set luminosity.

Alternatively use the sliders for the different color channels.

[image]

Or use the *Mouse Wheel* to adjust luminosity.

To reset the color wheel to default press the <kbd>⟵ Backspace</kbd>